Bridging two networks using Ubuntu
Good afternoon,
I would like to try combining two networks using Ubuntu (Ubuntu 16.04). More specifically, I have a DJI Tello drone, which generates its own Wi-Fi access point, and therefore the devices connected to its own Wi-Fi access point can only control the drone. However, what I would like to achieve is to connect this drone via Ubuntu as a bridge to my router, so that I can control the drone from other devices connected to the router, or using public IP by port forwarding.
Here's the current configuration.
Drone's access point (IP and settings cannot be altered) - wireless connection to Ubuntu (Blue line in the diagram)

Drone's address: 192.168.10.1
Ubuntu's address connected to the drone: 192.168.10.3
Default route from Ubuntu's side: 192.168.10.1

Router's access point (IP and settings can be altered) - wired connection to Ubuntu and wireless connection to other devices (Purple line in the diagram)

Router's (configuration page) address: 192.168.10.100
Ubuntu's address connected to the router: 192.168.10.50
Default route from Ubuntu's side: 192.168.10.100

If I can access the drone with its IP 192.168.10.1 from another devices connected to the router, I guess I can also do port forwarding or DMZ from the drone's IP to the public IP, so that I can access drone also from the external internet.
What I have done
I've installed the bridge-utils package to the Ubuntu, then set up the bridge interface as the above configuration via GUI. However, unless I manually adjust the metrics for the drone's wireless connection lower, I could not ping to 192.168.10.1 (drone). If I adjust the metrics value, then I could ping to both drone (192.168.10.1) and router (192.168.10.100) successfully. Unfortunately, when I tried to access the drone with its ip 192.168.10.1 from the other device attached to the router with IP 192.168.10.51 (MacBook), it says that there is no route to host.
Since the final goal is to access drone from the external internet, I would be glad to hear if there will be any configuration that I can adjust from Ubuntu's (or even Router's) side, so that virtually the drone is connected to the router as a client with its IP address, 192.168.10.1.
Any help on configuration will be appreciated.


However, unless I manually adjust the metrics for the drone's wireless connection lower

Bridging is an Ethernet-layer mechanism; its purpose is to turn both connections into one interface as far as Ethernet, IP, and other communication is concerned. Once the two interfaces are bridged, they should not have individual IP addresses anymore – the only IP addresses and routes (and therefore also metrics, which are a parameter of routes) should be on the newly created "bridge" interface, whereas any IP addresses or routes still remaining on the physical interfaces that have been turned into bridge ports will be ignored by the OS.
So if you still have default gateways on the individual connections (as well as the other symptoms), it sounds like the bridging configuration didn't work at all.
Indeed since both of your interfaces are Wi-Fi "client" connections (to external access points), they cannot be placed in bridges – a bridge is supposed to forward Ethernet frames as-is, but Wi-Fi is asymmetric and doesn't allow client devices to send frames on behalf of any other MAC address than the client's own. Because of that, Linux outright refuses to add a Wi-Fi client interface to a bridge. (AP interfaces of course can be bridged.)
Bridges on Windows, as well as devices such as Wi-Fi "repeaters" or "extenders", work around this by rewriting/NATing MAC addresses in flight (sometimes called "ARP NAT" or "MAC NAT"), but Linux doesn't have that feature built-in, as far as I know.
You'll need some alternative approach, instead of bridging:

Some off-the-shelf wireless routers or extenders can act as Wi-Fi clients, so this might be easier to achieve by getting such a router, connecting it via Ethernet to the primary router, and connecting it as a Wi-Fi client to the drone. Such a router might actually do routing with DNAT as below (requiring port-forward rules in both routers), or it might do bridging with ARP-NAT as described above (making it appear mostly transparent); either should work.

Routing with DNAT ("port forwarding") might be the most familiar, as that's what home routers do. Remove the bridge, change IP forwarding on the two interfaces (using sysctl), and change your router's IP network to one that wouldn't overlap with the drone's. Then add iptables DNAT rules to "port-forward" the necessary TCP or UDP ports to the drone's IP address. In effect you now have chained two routers.

Pure routing without "port forwarding" would be technically better, as long as your router actually allows static route configuration. As in the previous case, Remove the bridge, change IP forwarding on the two interfaces (using sysctl), and change your router's IP network to one that wouldn't overlap with the drone's. Instead of DNAT, however, configure the main router to have a static route towards the drone's 192.168.10.0/24 or .1/32 via the Ubuntu system. This will let your main network access the 192.168.10.1 address (as well as set up a port-forward rule to it) automatically crossing the Ubuntu-router.

Routing with proxy-ARP is an option that would allow both sides to have the same 192.168.10.0/24 network.



On a side note:

Ubuntu's address connected to the drone: 192.168.10.3
Default route from Ubuntu's side: 192.168.10.1

It doesn't make any practical sense to have a default gateway on the Wi-Fi connection to the drone, because the drone doesn't act as a gateway – and it has nowhere to gateway anything to, anyway. All that the drone Wi-Fi connection provides is a single isolated subnet, and you don't need a gateway for same-subnet communications, so it'd be better to just leave the field empty.

Thank you very much for your comment. I am not familiar to the networking, and therefore didn't understand the concept of the networking. I will try to try the methods that you have suggested, then let you know if it worked. Thank you very much.

By using iptables and PREROUTING rules, I was able to see that the UDP packet from the drone is successfully sent to designated IP:
$ sudo iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -j DNAT -p tcp --dport 8889 --to-destination 192.168.10.1:8889 $ sudo iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -j DNAT -p udp --dport 11111 --to-destination 192.168.10.1:11111
However, I wasn't able to make POSTROUTING rules working unfortunately. But I got an idea that instead of drone redirecting its packet to some IP address, it would be just better to run web server that enables the control of the drone on the Ubuntu.
